# my function in jquery that is testing if the mouse is down always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

i'm trying to test if the mouse is down or not so using mousedown() i try to set the value of down to true, but that never happens.

Heres the code

```
  function checkDown()
  {
    var down = false;
    $(document).mousedown(()=>{down = true;});
    return down;
  }
```

Comment: That code says "when the mouse becomes down, then assign true to down", which is slightly different from "if the mouse..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move down in global and event listener to the global;

```
var down = false; // by default will be false
$(document).mousedown(()=>{down = true;});// when mouse will be down it will make it true

function checkDown()
{
    return down;// returns the current status of down 
}
```

Comment: correct me if Im wrong, but if the script is only run once, mousedown is only checked once, and return down will always return the value of down when the script first loaded. How can I get around this

Comment: @Raza  `mousedown` is a function which takes a callback `$(document).mousedown(callback);`  and register to the mouse down event, every time mouse down event happens it will call the callback. Here we registering to event once which is correct. Now the last piece of puzzle is to solve   is resetting the down flag when mouseup. Give it a try